# Is there buffered lock pattern?

Tags: go, design-patterns

In Go there is a concept of *buffered* channel. That is a channel that will not be blocked until you fill its buffer.

Is there any general pattern for general *buffered locking*? It will lock some resource for limited amount of clients.

Comment: Google "semaphore". It's often implemented with a buffered channel in Go.

Comment: Channels are never "locked". I think your understanding of a buffered channel is _slightly_ off.

Comment: @Flimzy yes, sorry, what I meant is that sends to buffered channel are blocked when buffer is full (as it is noted it A Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primitive that locks some resource for a limited amount of clients is called a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

It's easily implemented with a buffered channel:

```
var semaphore = make(chan struct{}, 4) // allow four concurrent users

func f() {
    // Grab the lock. Blocks as long as 4 other invocations of f are still running.
    semaphore <- struct{}{}

    // Release the lock once we're done.
    defer func() { <-semaphore }()

    // Do work...
}
```