# Golang Run GC on OOM

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Does golang run GC and retry allocation when it faces OOM ?
We are facing an issue where the kubernetes pod (running the go code) gets OOM Killed when processing large files.

The go code processes many files, reading them line by line and for each line it parses (allocating some memory by create a parsed struct - local variable in the loop) and if matching some condition inserts it to a DB.
This is run concurrently for multiple clients.
This works fine with many clients having small files. But when it encounters a large sized file for a client it goes OOM.

We have the system running for a long time and don't see any memory leaks. Even the pprof analysis indicates no memory leak.

Comment: GC does not release memory, it can only reuse it. You cannot tell when you are out of memory from within a process, that is up to the system. If you can no longer allocate anything, you can not run the GC anyway.

Comment: No, the OOM killer just kills a process. There is no prior "warning". And also a "No" in case of failing to allocate memory in Go.

Comment: Go 1.19 now has a GOMEMLIMIT which allows more control in this sort of situation

Answer (score 0):

The OOM killer is the kernel's last resort when faced with memory pressure. "Either I sacrifice a process now, or the entire system may become unusable."

Because this is a last resort (for instance, the kernel will choose to reduce the amount of memory available for the filesystem cache long before invoking the OOM killer) the process that is chosen to be sacrificed has no say in this and there is no early warning<sup>1</sup>.

In your case you are probably not running out of physical memory but hitting a user-defined memory limit for your container. But the kernel uses the same facilities to enforce this limit too.

You must raise your memory limit to account for the worst case workload, or improve your program's memory consumption to stay within its limit.

Given that small files work fine, it stands to reason that you're not limiting the concurrency appropriately. If you spawn one goroutine for every line all at once, in terms of memory usage there's no fundamental difference to reading the whole file. [Concurrency can be easily limited with a semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004967/is-there-buffered-lock-pattern/60005206#60005206)

---

1. You can change the SIGKILL to a SIGTERM, but that won't help you here. Your ops team will hate you if you change the meaning of SIGTERM from "exit" to "release some memory to the OS but keep running". Not that Go has any way of doing so anyway.

Comment: The concurrency is with multiple clients and not each row of a file. A client will typically have 40-50 files having about 10k rows per file per window that we process.
We tried to explicitly add runtime.GC() after every 1000 rows processed and we see the large files also running fine with it. Seems we need to somehow tune the GC settings ?

Comment: @Pratham: you can tune the GC with the `GOGC` environment variable, but that can only delay the inevitable when the next lightly larger file is loaded into memory, or they are loaded slightly faster. You need to limit the memory consumption in some other way.